# When using JSTL in JSP, getting an exception

Tags: jsp, exception, jstl

Getting following exception when I have included:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
```

What I have done:

1. Included JSTL jar file WEB-INF/lib folder
2. Included Classpath in Run Configuration (using Eclipse)
3. Included in Build path too.

Comment: show the contents of `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I have included JSTL.jar(Version 1.2) and JSTL Standard.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: Included JSTL jar file WEB-INF/lib folder

Fine. That ought to be sufficient.

> 2: Included Classpath in Run Configuration (using Eclipse)
> 3: Included in Build path too.

Don't do. Eclipse does that automatically on 1. You need to undo all manual changes, they might make things worse.

> I have included JSTL.jar(Version 1.2) and JSTL Standard.jar

Get rid of `standard.jar`. JSTL 1.2 consists of only one JAR file. The `standard.jar` might want to locate classes which doesn't exist in JSTL 1.2 anymore, resulting in this kind of abstract/dependency errors.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both jstl.jar and standard.jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 version which has Servlet/JSP spec of 3.0/2.2

Answer (score 0):

Solution in eclipse:

Right click on

```
nameYourProject->java build path -> libraries -> add external jars
```

Go

```
 C:\Apachetomcat7\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\lib
```

Select all( `jstl` and `standart jar` ), click open

after import jstl and standart jar in project.