# Geting error while use jstl tag library in java web application

Tags: java, jsp

I got follow error when add taglib in jasp page like

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

my error is

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
```

exception is:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8021370/1031945

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874675/1031945

Answer (score 0):

You need [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl) jar in your web application classpath.